# Excel: How to create a dynamic range using values from different tables?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am making a personal excel sheet to keep track of the expenses of my car; fuel costs, how many liters, the cost/liter, the dates when I filled my gas tank, date of maintenance, etc.

I have already made the excel sheet show me the cost and liters used per day to drive the car (workday and regular day).

What I am trying to do is have excel note the change in fuel usage before and after maintenance date. For example, it would check the maintenance date and would only count the fueling dates set after it, and treat the maintenance date as the earliest fuel date in its calculations.

Currently I can get the number of days between the latest maintenance date and the latest fueling date with this:

```
=DAYS(IF(MAX('Gas Cost'!$C:$C)>MAX(Maintenance!$C:$C), MAX('Gas Cost'!$C:$C),MAX(Maintenance!$C:$C)),IF(MAX('Gas Cost'!$C:$C)>MAX(Maintenance!$C:$C), MAX(Maintenance!$C:$C),MAX('Gas Cost'!$C:$C)))
```

For me to get the actual price, I think what I have to do is use the dates acquired to get the cell row position, then move the column over to the price value, but that method would only give me the start and the end, not the range inbetween. But the issue with that is it only gives me the raw date value and I am not sure how to get Excel to search for the date if the lower date value is from Maintenance and not Gas Cost.

How do I make a dynamic range that uses the returned position values as reference to a different part of a table?

[image: Summary sheet]
[image: Gas Cost sheet]

Comment: Use `Sumifs()` formulas in the cells for Fuel Total and Liters Filled.